# Can I post review on Facebook particular Page through API if I have the Page access Token?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I was able to get the page ratings of the Page through GraphAPI but is it possible to post page review on the page through GraphAPI or User_actions or Open Graph

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for clearing my doubt

Comment: @NishigandhaAhire - post page review means

Comment: Review means the rating with rating message which anyone can give to a particular Facebook page of a particular user and i was searching for - was that possible through API post method?